# Azure Data Factory Pipeline trigger time

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

It may be simple but I am having hard time in understanding exact trigger time of Azure Data Factory Pipeline. I followed the MS tutorial to create a DF pipeline to copy data from Blob To Azure SQL.

I created a pipeline at "1-March 16:14 IST (10:44 AM UTC)" with below scheduled,

Start date - 02/28/2017 12:00 AM UTC

End date - 03/04/2017 11:59 PM UTC

Recurring in 1 Day

After creating pipeline, it immediately run for below window,

Window Start - 02/28/2017 12:00 AM UTC

Window End - 03/01/2017 12:00 AM UTC

Attempt End - 03/01/2017 10:45 AM UTC

Attempt Start - 03/01/2017 10:44 AM UTC

Now my question is why it didn't run for window (03/01/17 12:00 AM UTC to 03/02/17 12:00 AM UTC) because pipeline was created between this time window only. I mean it ran for last day window but not for current day window.

So what is exact time when a pipeline is triggered in every window?

---

**As asked by Paul, here are more configuration values,**

Pipeline:

```
"policy": {
            "timeout": "1.00:00:00",
            "concurrency": 1,
            "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst",
            "style": "StartOfInterval",
            "retry": 3,
            "longRetry": 0,
            "longRetryInterval": "00:00:00"
        },
        "scheduler": {
            "frequency": "Day",
            "interval": 1
        },

"start": "2017-02-28T00:00:00Z",
    "end": "2017-03-04T23:59:00Z",
```

Source Dataset:

```
"availability": {
        "frequency": "Day",
        "interval": 1
    },
    "external": true,
    "policy": {},
```

Destination Dataset:

```
"availability": {
        "frequency": "Day",
        "interval": 1
    },
    "external": false,
    "policy": {},
```

Below is the execution log,

```
Start & End Time
03/01/2017 12:00 AM UTC - 03/02/2017 12:00 AM UTC
Attempt Time : 03/02/2017 12:01 AM
```

Comment: It's definitely not simple. It's very complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Can you please provide the JSON for the pipeline schedule, the dataset internals (in and out) and copy activity scheduler?

The attribute values from these 4 different blocks of code is what affects the ADF time slice behaviour. There will be something you've missed in your configuration when you've provisioned the slices. Also be mindful that time slices are very different to a SQL Agent schedule, despite the poorly named JSON attribute of 'schedule'! This is simple the start and end of the **time line** that is to be **sliced** up by defined intervals.

Additionally there are settings to state what order to run things in and when the time slice should execute. Eg; at the start or the end.

This is a handy Microsoft article that I often refer to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution

Hope this helps.

Comment: One point is clear that DF Pipeline can be triggered either at the end of window or beginning of the window. In my case it is getting triggered at the end of window. But why? I will update my question with more relevant data as you asked.

Comment: If you use the 'style' attribute you can control that. StartOfInterval or EndOfInterval.

Comment: in Pipeline configuration, style = StartOfInterval. But still it runs at the end of scheduling window.

Comment: Thanks for including the JSON above. It ran the newest slice time within the schedule. As per the policy attribute above... "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst".

Comment: Thanks Paul, it is really getting interesting now. I further check about executionPriorityOrder on below link. It says "Determines the ordering of data slices that are being processed.
For example, if you have 2 slices (one happening at 4pm, and another one at 5pm), and both are pending execution. If you set the executionPriorityOrder to be NewestFirst, the slice at 5 PM is processed first. Similarly if you set the executionPriorityORder to be OldestFIrst, then the slice at 4 PM is processed." 
I see it applies to pending slices and has nothing to do with current slice.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-create-pipelines